# How to cast type of Pandas data to use outside of Pandas

Tags: arrays, pandas, if-statement, casting

I'm trying to learn to use Pandas and want to sort through a list of data by the quality of my data which is given in my csv, which i read in.
Since I am only trained in coding in C++, my first intention is to use if cases:
So what I did is:

```
tbl = pd.read_csv(data)


for Quality in tbl:
    if tbl['Quality'] is int:
        if tbl['Quality']<=4:
            qlt_tbl = tbl['Quality']
```

Since my new table qlt_tbl always stayed empty I looked, why my if case is never used and found the type of my "Quality"-row to be pandas.core.series.Series.
Is there any way to typecast these, so they become usable?
If not could you give me a way to do it within pandas (which there certainly is, but I didn't find yet)?

Thanks in advance

PS: What I tried:

I tried typecasting with tbl.to_int, which seemingly doesn't exist in Pandas.
I tried tbl.sort_values([by=['Quality'], asscending=True) but am unsure how to use only specific qualities now, which is, why i wanted to build a shorter list containing only those entries with `tbl['Quality']<=4`
I tried to find other methods to read my csv, but since my college uses this, Pandas really is my only way.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
for i in tbl['Quality']:
    if i[0].dtype==int:
        if i[0].dtype<4:
            qlt_tbl.append(i)
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work, because int is not subscriptable